# Table does not exist in Spring boot hibernate JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

iam trying to develop small API POC in spring boot but consistently getting Table does not exist error I believe hibernate automatically creates a table in database.

here is my code
..............................................................

Application.java

```
package FirstPackage;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }

}
```

........................................................................................

MainController.java

```
package FirstPackage;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller   //This refers as this is main controller class
@RequestMapping("/main")   //This means request will be mapping on localhost:8081/main 
public class MainController {

    @Autowired   //This means Spring will take care of this object creation
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @PostMapping(path = "/add")
    public @ResponseBody String addNewStudent(@RequestParam String name)/*, @RequestParam Integer roll_Number, @RequestParam String standerd)*/
    {
        Student s = new Student();
        s.setName(name);
        s.setRoll_Number(101);
        s.setStanderd("I");
        studentRepository.save(s);
        return "Data Entered";
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/all")
    public Iterable<Student> getAllStudent()
    {
        return studentRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

...........................................................................................

Student.java

```
package FirstPackage;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/*this is going to be entity Model this tell Hibernate to make a table out of it */
@Entity
@Table(name = "students_table")
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer roll_Number;
    private String standerd;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Integer getRoll_Number() {
        return roll_Number;
    }

    public void setRoll_Number(Integer roll_Number) {
        this.roll_Number = roll_Number;
    }
    public String getStanderd() {
        return standerd;
    }

    public void setStanderd(String standerd) {
        this.standerd = standerd;
    }
}
```

.....................................................................................

```
package FirstPackage;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import FirstPackage.Student;

//This will be AUTO IMPLEMENTED by Spring into a Bean called StudentRepository
//CRUD refers Create, Read, Update, Delete
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, Integer> 
{

}
```

......................................................................................
application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.dll-auto = create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3303/db_student
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=Root@1234
```

Comment: use spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto. There is syntax mistake in spring.jpa.hibernate.dll-auto

Comment: should i remove "=  create"

Comment: no, use spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create // here Hibernate first drops existing tables, then it will create new tables

Comment: Thanks this solves the error!!